# Assertions in recursive call?

Tags: java

This is a code to check if the graph is bipartite or not. My question is regarding assertions.
I want a check to validate if graph is null or not. Effective java encourages checks even in private functions. Lets say I add an assert graph != null, it would be checked as many times the recursive function is called. This appears inefficient. If the check if done before recursive function is called, then we violate best practices stated in effective java, that every function should validate parameters.Is there some best practice / tradeoff etc? Thanks.

```
private void dfsBipartiteDetector(Graph graph, int vertex, int i) {
    assert graph != null; // <--------- appears inefficient for recursive call.

    visited[vertex] = true;

    vertexSets.get(i).add(vertex);

    final List<Integer> adjList = graph.adj(vertex);
    for (int v : adjList) {
        if (!visited[v]) {
            dfsBipartiteDetector(graph, v, i == 0 ? 1 : 0);
        } else {
            if (vertexSets.get(i).contains(v)) {
                isBipartite = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance of `assert` but I have the feeling that is extremely quick.

Comment: When run without assertions enabled, there shouldn't be any measurable effect of using assert. However in this case, you'd get a NPE anyways in this method (and not somewhere down the stack where it would be hard to find the cause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assert` isn't on by default. The check only actually runs if you explicitly enable it by starting the JVM with the `-ea` option. The idea is to enable assertions while in development, and disable in production to solve the very tradeoff you mention.

Having said that, I find it useful to have such checks on in production, and this is why I prefer using Guava's `Preconditions` instead of `assert` keyword, because checks using the former will always run. Performance drop due to this kind of checks are usually negligible compared to other parts of your code, and it can help debugging hard to debug bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Trading efficiency for safety in debug-only code is good practice.

It's pretty common to add quite complex debug-only sanity-checking code, to check the integrity of a whole data structure for instance.

Only if the code slows down so much that it gets in the way of your development process should you think about reducing the amount of such checking.